# Graphing Random Forest with Tree for Linear Regression

Tags: python, random-forest, pygraphviz

I am having a problem graphing my linear regression model with a random forest. Also, I am having a problem defining my feature_names and class_names because it is a continuous number. In R, this is a fairly simple visual, but python seems to require a little more thought.

I am utilizing the NYC Property data to predict future housing prices. I want to visualize this in a decision tree.

```
python
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
random_forest = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=12)
random_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

estimator = random_forest.estimators_[5]

export_graphviz(
    estimator,
    out_file="nyc_tree.dot",
    rounded=True,
    filled=True
)
```

I expect a decision tree with several branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of issue are you encountering? Making your data is not shaped the right way (n_samples,n_features) for X, and (n_samples) for y.

Otherwise, this [website](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-visualize-a-decision-tree-from-a-random-forest-in-python-using-scikit-learn-38ad2d75f21c) might help you, it's doing exactly what your looking for.

Comment: I tried using that resource but i get this error. `Length of feature_names, 47005 does not match number of features, 9` Because my input is a linear continue integer. Also the code above does work, but when i used a website it couldn't render the dot file

Comment: What is the shapes for your X and y? You should have: `X.shape[0] == y.shape`. If it's not the case, maybe you should transpose your `X_train`. If it does not, could you provide a small sample of your data in your post?

Comment: For the dot file, you could convert it to .png for instance (it worked for me on a Mac computer with graphviz)